# Mongo: "Waiting for replication not allowed"

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy, spring-data-mongodb

I have a tiny groovy script to run `.mongo` file against a replica set of Mongo DB ver. 3.6:

```
ScriptOperations scriptOps = new MongoTemplate( mongoClient, 'mydb' ).scriptOps()

[ 'inx.mongo', 'roles.mongo' ].each{
  try{
    ExecutableMongoScript s = new ExecutableMongoScript( new File( it ).text )
    def res = scriptOps.execute s
    log.info "processed $it >> $res"
  }catch( Throwable t ){
    log.error "$it --> $t"
  }
}
```

When the script is run, I'm getting the log:

> 10:22:23.017 [main] INFO Migrator - processed inx.mongo >> [retval:[createdCollectionAutomatically:false, numIndexesBefore:4, numIndexesAfter:4, note:all indexes already exist, ok:1.0, operationTime:Timestamp{value=6608816253102456876, seconds=1538734942, inc=44}, $clusterTime:[clusterTime:Timestamp{value=6608816253102456876, seconds=1538734942, inc=44}, signature:[hash:org.bson.types.Binary@c98f581, keyId:0]]], ok:1.0, operationTime:Timestamp{value=6608816253102456876, seconds=1538734942, inc=44}, $clusterTime:[clusterTime:Timestamp{value=6608816253102456876, seconds=1538734942, inc=44}, signature:[hash:org.bson.types.Binary@c98f581, keyId:0]]]
>
> 10:22:23.087 [main] ERROR Migrator - roles.mongo --> com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 139: 'Error: Waiting for replication not allowed while holding a lock :
>   _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
>   DB.prototype.updateRole@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1713:19
>   @:1:1
>   ' on server mozaiq_mongo2_1:27002. The full response is { "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1538734942, "i" : 44 } }, "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Error: Waiting for replication not allowed while holding a lock :\n_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13\nDB.prototype.updateRole@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1713:19\n@:1:1\n", "code" : 139, "codeName" : "JSInterpreterFailure", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1538734942, "i" : 44 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "0" } } } }

So the 1st file `inx.mongo` seems to be processed fine, but the 2nd one `roles.mongo` throws the `Error: Waiting for replication not allowed while holding a lock`.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: What if you change the order of the scripts being run: `roles.mongo` goes first?

Comment: maybe the problem in mongo scripts and not in java/groovy? is it possible to provide those two mongo scripts?

Comment: the scripts are fine, as they can be executed from mongo console. one of them is creating role/privileges, the other one creates indicies. If I leave the role-script out, the job runs w/o exceptions.

Comment: just interesting will it work if you use Thread.sleep(xxxx) between executions ? maybe something connected with async in script?

Comment: tried it already... the exception is thrown during execution of roles-script